# windows phone 8 app development using phone gap and cordova

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am started windows phone 8 mobile app developement i am using windows8 visualstudio express 2012 .

please help me i am in started using phonegap with jquery mobile  how to start developement .

thanks,

Comment: You'll have to look up beginner tutorials and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if i can be useful here;

You should learn Javascript first if you haven't already.  Doing so will put you in a good place for any jquery development.

Learn jquery by going to http://jquery.com/.  There are many samples and a lot of information.

Learn JQuery mobile by going to http://jquerymobile.com/.  Again, lots and lots of samples and examples here.  The good thing about JQM is that it allows you to have a uniform look and feel for all your mobile apps across platforms.  It also provides handy code for transitions, headers, footers, mapping etc without you needing to code anything.

Learn PhoneGap by going to the site and trying a few things.

Start off with a small app and build from there.

Have a "**clear**" idea in you mind of what you want to accomplish **Before** you begin and make a plan to get there in small hops.

**Edit**

Also learning about AJAX and JSON might be of some use depending on the type of application you are writing.  It's kinda difficult to give any specific help as you haven't provided us with much to go on.